# Work out value and push into model when called

Tags: c#, .net

So what this code is supposed to do is work out how many 'likes' a user has and then return that value as the 'UserPhoto.Likes' value. Currently i'm getting the whole 'UserPhoto' model and working out the 'Likes' but not putting the two together like I want it to.

```
    [HttpGet("{userId}/photo/{photoId}")]
    public async Task<IQueryable> GetUserPhoto(int userId, int photoId)
    {
        var photos = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Include(p => p.Likers);

        var photo = photos.Where(x => x.Id == photoId);

        var likes = _repo.CountUserLikes(userId, photoId);
        // this line gets the total amount of likes for that photo

        var whole = photo.Include(x => x.Likes as likes);
        // this line is where I tried to send 'Likes' as 'likes'

        return whole;
    }
```

This is what should be returned from this request, just with the correct amount of likes (as you can see there is 1 like there, so likes should say 1, but it says 0. Also there is no error in the line

```
var likes = _repo.CountUserLikes(userId, photoId);
```

as this does return the correct amount of likes, I've tested it

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "photoUrl": "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39810479_537470876724057_5547938285650706432_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=MBSkwH6PVzgAX9iSKsc&oh=39e4f480573fc78cf0afefb8820cdd19&oe=5EB8228C",
        "description": "Non deserunt labore sunt ex laboris et adipisicing ullamco officia minim.",
        "dateAdded": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "isMain": true,
        "publicId": null,
        "isImage": true,
        "mainImage": "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39810479_537470876724057_5547938285650706432_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=MBSkwH6PVzgAX9iSKsc&oh=39e4f480573fc78cf0afefb8820cdd19&oe=5EB8228C",
        "userId": 1,
        "likers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "imageId": 1,
                "likerId": 1
            }
        ],
        "likes": 0
    }
]
```

Also, in the model, 'Likes' is just an integer value:

```
 public int Likes { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you not do something like public int Likes { get => likers.Count() }

Comment: Okay, i've done that and it works but will that create a static value for likes? it needs to be dynamic as the amount of likes can increase or decrease

Comment: No it will not be static. The Count() method will be called every time that property is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ryan Thomas said, you can simply declare the Likes property as a read-only property which returns the count of the likers whenever it's accessed:

`public int Likes => likers.Count()`

This is not a static value, it's a property on each object.

I think the .Include() method is not really clear to you. I would suggest to look it up a bit more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data). In reality though, it is used to add more data to the return result from tables that you did not specify in your query, but are connected with your table.